# Assigning model as list C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, list, models

[image]
Why doesn't my list `files` get any values?
I have another page with same logic and everything works fine.

I can provide more code if needed.

```
public ActionResult TestPDF(List<int> fileid)
    {

        List<object> myModel = new List<object>();
        List<object> obj = new List<object>();

        foreach (var id in fileid)
        {          
            obj.Add(db.UploadedFiles.Find(id));
        }
        myModel.Add(obj);

        return View(myModel);
    }
```

Comment: Yep, checked that. Still get an exception. @m.rogalski

Comment: Because you're trying to cast an UploadedFile to a List<UploadedFile> using 'as', which will return null because it's not valid.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry I wasn't careful enough in your snapshot. You `Model` is a collection of `IEnumerable<UploadedFile>`, so the `[0]` is indeed needed to get the first `IEnumerable<UploadedFile>`. So what you need to do is:

```
List<Upload.Models.UploadedFile> files = Model.ToList()[0].ToList();
```

Or you could just enum the files like:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.ToList()[0])
{
    ...
}
```

**EDIT**: 
A better way is to modify your controller so that it returns strong typed model, and get rid of the unnecessary nested List:

```
public ActionResult TestPDF(List<int> fileid)
{

    var myModel = new List<UploadedFile>();

    foreach (var id in fileid)
    {          
        myModel.Add(db.UploadedFiles.Find(id));
    }

    return View(myModel);
}
```

Then you could modify the `@model` in your view to

```
@model List<Upload.Models.UploadedFile>
```

And loop the files by

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
{
    ...
}
```

**EDIT 2**
Assuming you are using Entity Framework, you could refine the controller further more to:

```
public ActionResult TestPDF(List<int> fileid)
{
    List<Upload.Models.UploadedFile> myModel = fileid == null ? new List<Upload.Models.UploadedFile>() : db.UploadedFiles.Where(o => fileid.Contains(o.ID)).ToList();

    return View(myModel);
}
```

Comment: When `[0]` removed I will get an error: Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<Upload.Models.UploadedFile>'. Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<object>' to 'List<UploadedFile>' via a built-in conversion.

Comment: I also forgot to mention, that at the top of the page I have `@model IEnumerable<object>`

Comment: could you show the code in your controller? If you are passing a list of `Upload.Models.UploadedFile` to the view,  you should add `@model IEnumerable<Upload.Models.UploadedFile>` in the beginning of the view to make a strong typed view

Comment: Is there a reason you can't define it as IEnumerable<UploadedFile>?

Comment: (If you really can't, you could use .OfType<UploadedFile>)

Comment: Thank you. This finally solved my problem! @EvanHuang